# How to efficiently assemble a stiffness matrix multiple times using cython

Tags: python, scipy, cython

I am writing my own finite element solver for dynamic simulations in cython using the [ceygen](https://github.com/strohel/Ceygen) library (wrapped memory view of Eigen's vectors and matrices). In each time step I have to assemble the stiffness matrix and estimate its largest eigenvalue with the Gerschgoring circle theorem, by adding the absolute of each row entry in the matrix. For the assembly I am using the `coo_matrix` format. Here is a short version of my assembly code:

```
for el in range(nElemens):

    Klocal()

    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            data(index) = Klocal(i,j)
            index += 1

K = coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(ndof, ndof)).tocsc()
K.eliminate_zeros()
```

When running a profiler I get the following results:

```
 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall  filename:lineno(function)
  458    264.720  0.578    264.720  0.578    {built-in method lexsort}
    1    84.764   84.764   486.663  486.663  main.py:9(main)
  458    61.473   0.134    343.218  0.749    coo.py:460(_sum_duplicates)
  458    12.933   0.028    12.933   0.028    {method 'reduceat' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
 2775    11.192   0.004    11.193   0.004    {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
16063    8.627    0.001    8.627    0.001    {built-in method array}
28419916 6.933    0.000    6.933    0.000    membrane3D.pyx:366(membrane3DKmat)
```

A massive amount of time is lost by the `lexsort` and `reduceat` functions internally called by scipy every single time I assemble the matrix. My question is whether I can re-use the non-zero structure of the matrix (which stays constant and can be easily computed) in scipy to save time? Or alternatively, would you recommend me to use a wrapper for the Eigen's sparse matrix?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Us the sparsity structure tge same each time?  If so it might be faster to build a `csr` format directly, or even change just the `,data` attribute.

Comment: I edited my post and added a short pseudo code of the assembly. Essentially I am only changing `data` in each iteration and let scipy sparse do the job of creating the sparse matrix. Would using the `crs` format directly still allow me to add multiple contributions on a single degree of freedom of the matrix like in the `coo` format?

Comment: `csr/csc` has a `sum_duplicates` method.  Normally that's called during the conversion from `coo` to `csr`.  In general to get good speed changing a `csc` matrix, you need to understand and use the `indptr`, `indices` and `data` arrays directly.